# How can I resize a DIV's height to 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have now searched for hours, but haven't found a solution yet. I hope anyone out there can help me :)

I searched and found the following script: http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/81/

This script is great but if the div#center isn't full of content, it looks like the following: jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/80/

I actually want to resize it to 100% height even if it isn't full of content. Is this possible and if yes: How?
I really don't get it.

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Thank you all for your help!

With my own design it now looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/102/
The problem is, that you now can scroll even if there is no content.

**Edit2:** I have found the issue! There was a padding too much in #content.

Comment: Do you want `#center` to be 100% width? I'm not sure I fully understand your question here. Did you want `#left` to be up against the side?

Comment: are those examples supposed to be different?

Comment: Hey! No, I want #center to be 100% HEIGHT. #left should stay as it is.

Comment: for which browser,it's not working? it looks ok in firefox.

Comment: Maybe this example is better: http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/83/

I actually want that #center's height is 100%, but if there is more content it should look like http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/81/ (with content scrolling only)

Or in other words: It should always look like http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/81/ even if in #center is no or less content.

Comment: is this what you wanted http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/86/

Comment: @Dampsquid's example, fixing for the `#header` height affect on `#center`: http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/89/ (Note, that doesn't work.)

Comment: Yes! Nice! Thank you, guys! I changed Dampsquid's example in http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/95/ This works perfect for me! Thank you again!

Comment: actually it is not solved :( I tried it on my own design now but if there is less text you can scroll http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/102/. Anyone can help?

Comment: Maddin, several people are posting answers for you below.  You should be interacting with them and/or editing your original question instead of trying to solve this via comments.  This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @Sparky672 thank you for the tips. Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: When using SO, it's important to keep in mind that these questions & answers are also here to help future readers.  I appreciate your effort to learn and conform.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my answer is here..

http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/101/

edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/103/ ( this is with text which extends beyond body, just added to show that css changes works for both the cases.. )

what i did was added

height:100% to html,body and #bind

and added min-height:100% to #center

based on this

http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/

Comment: This is good, but if I try it on my own design there is a scrollbar even if there is no content: http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/102

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/NFa8b/) should work.

The likely problem is that you assume that the body and html containers default to 100% width and 100% height. This is not the case. By default, the width is 100% but the height adjusts to the content inside the html/body containers.

Hopefully I understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

[this one will work](http://jsfiddle.net/NFa8b/1/), even if the content exceeds the div.

setting `min-height: 100`% instead of fixing `height:100%` ensures a flexible div.